# My Vue NPM imports can only find the modules if they are inside the src folder and not project root

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nodes

In my app root, I have /node_modules/ and /src/

I have ran npm install and installed packages using npm install axios --save etc for all my dependencies
I do see that they are being added to the node_modules directory however my vue project does not compile with the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios' in '/app/src'
```

If I manually create a node_modules folder inside of my /src/ directory, and place axios, and my other dependencies it works.. but from what I've read I should not be handling my node modules this way. It seems I need to have my dependencies point to a different path?

What's weird is my import Vue from 'vue' and App from './App.vue' work fine, it's basically everything afterwards that fails to compile..

My main.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/analytics";
import "firebase/firestore";
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  firebase: firebase,
}).$mount('#app')
```

I have also tried removing all node modules, clearing NPM cache and reinstalling NPM dependencies to no avail.

Comment: please show me your whole main.js, not only the imports

Comment: @Deniz main.js has been updated

Answer (score 0):

instead of use the `use` function to add your axios instance globally can you please try to add it like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/analytics";
import "firebase/firestore";
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.prototype.$axios = Axios; //<---- like that

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  firebase: firebase,
}).$mount('#app')
```

after that try to compile again. you are then able to call your axios instance on every component with `this.$axios`

Comment: Hey Deniz, I tried that and it throws the same error:

`Failed to compile.

./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios' in '/app/src'`

Comment: right below where you do your import axios try this: `console.log(axios)` check the result and tell me if its gives a hint.
otherwise try to make a screenshot of your project tree with all expanded if possible

Comment: The console.log doesn't produce any extra information, just the same error as above, here is a screenshot of my project structure:https://i.imgur.com/DmLKVup.png 

If I rename that node_modulesOLD to node_modules, the project will compile, if I leave it as OLD I get the error stated above. Although it seems super counterintuitive to load 2 sets of node packages in 1 project. Ignore that weirdly named ReadMe, I simply erased a sensitive title.

Comment: what is this `package-lock.json` in src folder? package-lock should be in root only. also please remove the `node_modulesOLD` as well. best would be delete all your `package-lock.json` and try `npm install` again

Comment: package-lock.json, package.json and node_modules must be in root folder. they must be in the very same folder where your correct node_modules is

Comment: Deleted all node_module and package-lock.json files, reran npm install from the project root: no luck and still throws the same error. `./src/main.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios' in '/app/src'`

This is current project structure now: https://i.imgur.com/vBEovgc.png

Comment: is this a vue-cli created project?

Comment: Not sure it's first origins, it was a forked project from github, its running inside of a docker container if that helps

Comment: Ahhh.. show me the docker file pls. Maybe its bacause of the docker Environment

Comment: I just noticed it does work with npm run serve, but not with docker run -v